# jQuery assign empty input value to a variable

Tags: jquery

How can I assign an empty input to a variable?

```
submitForm: function(){
    if($('input[name=firstname]').val() === '' || $('input[name=lastname]').val() === '' || $('input[name=age]').val() === ''){
        var empty = 'empty value';
        empty.addClass('error');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

},
```

Comment: what do you mean, assign to a variable? `var foo = $('input[name=firstname]');`?

Comment: You need to explain a bit better

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the empty fields in a form.

You need this:

```
var someval = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
```

And then use it to check as `someval == ''`

Error was `input[name=firstname]`. Note the qoutations.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/PYPzx/1/

You can change the if block to `alert`.

Comment: Note: The quotations dont really mind, I never use them for this

Comment: But I got errors while creating an ajax request and the request was sent with empty form. So I had to update the code with qoutes :)

Comment: Note that the usual convention is not to capitalize JavaScript variables unless they're constructor functions. Unfortunately, the language doesn't have a built-in way to distinguish constructors, and mistaking them for ordinary functions can cause big problems.